# Does tinymce have an option, via menu, to insert form fields into it or just by editing the code?

Tags: forms, plugins, tinymce, field

Does anyone know of a ready-made plugin that allows adding input, textarea, select etc. on tinymce?

Answer (score 0):

The `tinymce.dom.Selection` API (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#select) allows you to select elements or set content in the TinyMCE editor. You can assign the API class to an action or an interaction element like a button or form, and any selected content will be replaced with the contents the API action passes in.

If that's not a good fit for what you need, is there an example of the type of adding input, a textarea, or a select you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There are no official plugins that allow such interactive elements to be added. TinyMCE is a text editor that is built to create blog posts, articles, etc. By design, it is not a page builder. However, there may be some unofficial plugins on GitHub that may implement such features.

If you are going to insert forms and text areas that should not be edited or reconfigured afterward, you can use [templates](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/template/). They may come as any valid HTML. Thus, some fixed forms can be just saved as templates.

Another way is, of course, inserting HTML directly into the [code](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/code/).